# Cannot install 'discord-music-bot' with NPM

Tags: node.js, npm-install, discord, discord.io

Here's what I'm doing in CMD, the bot is running perfectly but I cannot install the NPM.

```
C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Projects\PBodyBot>npm i discord-music-bot
npm WARN deprecated snekfetch@3.6.4: use node-fetch instead

> ref@1.3.5 install C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Projects\PBodyBot\node_modules\ref
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Projects\PBodyBot\node_modules\ref>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Projects\PBodyBot\node_modules\ref
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok

> node-opus@0.2.9 install C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Projects\PBodyBot\node_modules\node-opus
> node-gyp rebuild


C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Projects\PBodyBot\node_modules\node-opus>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )
gyp ERR! configure error
gyp ERR! stack Error: Can't find Python executable "C:\Program Files (x86)\Python37-32\python.EXE", you can set the PYTHON env variable.
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.failNoPython (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:483:19)
gyp ERR! stack     at PythonFinder.<anonymous> (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\node-gyp\lib\configure.js:508:16)
gyp ERR! stack     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\graceful-fs\polyfills.js:284:29
gyp ERR! stack     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:152:21)
gyp ERR! System Windows_NT 10.0.17134
gyp ERR! command "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\node_modules\\node-gyp\\bin\\node-gyp.js" "rebuild"
gyp ERR! cwd C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\Projects\PBodyBot\node_modules\node-opus
gyp ERR! node -v v8.9.4
gyp ERR! node-gyp -v v3.6.2
gyp ERR! not ok
npm WARN Invalid version: "1"
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of bufferutil@^3.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of erlpack@discordapp/erlpack but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of opusscript@^0.0.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of sodium@^2.0.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of libsodium-wrappers@^0.7.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN discord.js@11.4.2 requires a peer of uws@^9.14.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN PBodyBot No description
npm WARN PBodyBot No repository field.
npm WARN PBodyBot No README data
npm WARN PBodyBot No license field.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ref@1.3.5 (node_modules\ref):
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: ref@1.3.5 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Exit status 1

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! node-opus@0.2.9 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the node-opus@0.2.9 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Alex\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2018-09-23T18_41_05_429Z-debug.log
```

I've been at this trying to figure it out for hours, and I've searched all around SO, but for everyone else it seems to be a problem with their code and not installing the NPM itself.  I am running Windows 10 and Node version v8.9.4.

I also tried running CMD as administrator but that didn't do anything.

Other things I've tried:
Setting the Python dir
Un-installing and re-installing Node
Updating discord.io

Comment: Run for windows: `npm install --global --production windows-build-tools` `npm install -g node-gyp`. Read more: https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp

Comment: @Lemix thank you this worked, maybe you should post this as an answer so people will see it if they have the same problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need install build tools on Windows:

```
npm install -g node-gyp
npm install --global --production windows-build-tools
```

More information: [node-gyp](https://github.com/nodejs/node-gyp)